# CSS3 Media Queries Current Page Size

Tags: css, media-queries

Using the Google Chrome browser, what is the easiest way to determine the page size, so you can write an appropriate css3 media query.

Currently I slowly resize the browser to spot any areas where a css3 media query could be used to improve the increasingly squashed interface but need a way to know the size the query should be used for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ahh I found a good way. In the Google Chrome inspector go to the console tab and enter the following:

`document.body.offsetWidth`

This will print out the current page width :)

Comment: No, this is not the same as viewport width, which the `width` media feature looks at.